# reference initialization from a temporary object's member data issue

Tags: c++, reference

A non-const reference can be bound only to an lvalue so I have tried this:

```
struct Foo
{
    double value = 5.45;
    operator double&(){return value;}
};

int main()
{

    double& d = Foo{};
    cout << d << endl; // seems ok 5.45

}
```

- `d` is a reference initialized from an unnamed temporary object `Foo{}`'s member data `value` but that temporary is destroyed at the next semi-colon which means it destroys also its member `value` but `d` is still referencing it. So why I get the correct value `5.45`? Does my code yield a UB? Is `d` a dangling referencing now? please explain Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior land.

Comment: "*So why I get the correct value 5.45?*" Undefined behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why I get the correct value 5.45?

Because the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> Does my code yield a UB?

Yes. You access an object outside of its lifetime.

> Is d a dangling referencing now?

Yes. As you said: The temporary object along with its member have been destroyed. All previously valid references to the destroyed object have become invalid i.e. dangling.

> ```
> // seems ok 5.45
> ```

It might seem OK, but it is nevertheless not OK.

Answer (score 0):

If 'd' is still referencing 'value' and 'd' is a non-const lvalue reference of type 'double&', agree? Then have you tried binding 'd' to an rvalue of type 'double' ?